# Quasar QSelect is not opening when performing AJAX call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I have been trying to create a simple `auto complete` using [Quasar's select](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#filtering-and-autocomplete) but I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

### Problem

Whenever I click the `QSelect` component, it doesn't show the dropdown where I can pick the options from.

[video of the problem](https://youtu.be/VblLWyBL4aw)

As soon as I click on the `QSelect` component, I make a request to fetch a list of 50 tags, then I populate the `tags` to my `QSelect` but the dropdown doesn't show.

### Code

```js
import type { PropType } from "vue";
import { defineComponent, h, ref } from "vue";
import type { TagCodec } from "@/services/api/resources/tags/codec";
import { list } from "@/services/api/resources/tags/actions";
import { QSelect } from "quasar";

export const TagAutoComplete = defineComponent({
  name: "TagAutoComplete",
  props: {
    modelValue: { type: Array as PropType<TagCodec[]> },
  },
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  setup(props, context) {
    const loading = ref(false);

    const tags = ref<TagCodec[]>([]);

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    const onFilterTest = (val: string, doneFn: (update: Function) => void) => {
      const parameters = val === "" ? {} : { title: val };

      doneFn(async () => {
        loading.value = true;
        const response = await list(parameters);

        if (val) {
          const needle = val.toLowerCase();
          tags.value = response.data.data.filter(
            (tag) => tag.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1
          );
        } else {
          tags.value = response.data.data;
        }

        loading.value = false;
      });
    };

    const onInput = (values: TagCodec[]) => {
      context.emit("update:modelValue", values);
    };

    return function render() {
      return h(QSelect, {
        modelValue: props.modelValue,
        multiple: true,
        options: tags.value,
        dense: true,
        optionLabel: "title",
        optionValue: "id",
        outlined: true,
        useInput: true,
        useChips: true,
        placeholder: "Start typing to search",
        onFilter: onFilterTest,
        "onUpdate:modelValue": onInput,
        loading: loading.value,
      });
    };
  },
});
```

### What I have tried

I have tried to use the several props that is available for the component but nothing seemed to work.

My understanding is that whenever we want to create an `AJAX` request using `QSelect` we should use the `onFilter` event emitted by `QSelect` and handle the case from there.

### Questions

- Is this the way to create a Quasar AJAX Autocomplete? (I have tried to search online but all the answers are in Quasar's forums that are currently returning `BAD GATEWAY`)
- What am I doing wrong that it is not displaying the dropdown as soon as I click on the `QSelect`?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but why make an async api call when you only have 50 option values in your QSelect? It looks like you're filtering twice if passing parameters to list() is meant to filter at the api. Also on first glance, try making onFilterTest async and await doneFn

Comment: @James I'm making an async call because it can contain all the way up to thousands (tags of technologies). The filtering happens because if we have the following in the options array `[1, 2, 3]` and then we get `[1, 4, 5]` from the api the `options` will have `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. The `1` is repeated. That's what we are doing in the `response.data.data.filter(...)`. I tried making `onFilterTest` async but without any luck. It still doesn't open the dropdown as soon as it is clicked (even though there are option to be displayed)

Comment: But if you want the dropdown to show immediately when you click, you should be preloading the tags...there's nothing to filter when you first click on the QSelect and tags isn't populated until you've changed the input value by typing something. Also, you specifically mention the quanty 50 tags in your post ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `updateFn` may not allow being `async`. Shift the `async` action a level up to [solve the issue](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#lazy-loading).

```js
const onFilterTest = async (val, update /* abort */) => {
  const parameters = val === '' ? {} : { title: val };
  loading.value = true;

  const response = await list(parameters);
  let list = response.data.data;
  if (val) {
    const needle = val.toLowerCase();
    list = response.data.data.filter((x) => x.title.toLowerCase()
      .includes(needle));
  }
  update(() => {
    tags.value = list;
    loading.value = false;
  });
};
```

I tested it by the following code and mocked values.

```js
// import type { PropType } from 'vue';
import { defineComponent, h, ref } from 'vue';
// import type { TagCodec } from "@/services/api/resources/tags/codec";
// import { list } from "@/services/api/resources/tags/actions";
import { QSelect } from 'quasar';

export const TagAutoComplete = defineComponent({
  name: 'TagAutoComplete',
  props: {
    modelValue: { type: [] },
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],

  setup(props, context) {
    const loading = ref(false);

    const tags = ref([]);

    const onFilterTest = async (val, update /* abort */) => {
      // const parameters = val === '' ? {} : { title: val };
      loading.value = true;
      const response = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve({
            data: {
              data: [
                {
                  id: 1,
                  title: 'Vue',
                },
                {
                  id: 2,
                  title: 'Vuex',
                },
                {
                  id: 3,
                  title: 'Nuxt',
                },
                {
                  id: 4,
                  title: 'SSR',
                },
              ],
            },
          });
        }, 3000);
      });

      let list = response.data.data;
      if (val) {
        const needle = val.toLowerCase();
        list = response.data.data.filter((x) => x.title.toLowerCase()
          .includes(needle));
      }
      update(() => {
        tags.value = list;
        loading.value = false;
      });
    };

    const onInput = (values) => {
      context.emit('update:modelValue', values);
    };

    return function render() {
      return h(QSelect, {
        modelValue: props.modelValue,
        multiple: true,
        options: tags.value,
        dense: true,
        optionLabel: 'title',
        optionValue: 'id',
        outlined: true,
        useInput: true,
        useChips: true,
        placeholder: 'Start typing to search',
        onFilter: onFilterTest,
        'onUpdate:modelValue': onInput,
        loading: loading.value,
      });
    };
  },
});
```